# Объединим [vue.js] и [vuejs]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю слить все в метку [vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js), поскольку в ней больше вопросов и, вроде, так будет правильней.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Предпросмотр объединения

[vuejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) будет **удалена** из **4** вопросов

[vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) будет **добавлена** к **4** вопросам

**A tag synonym mapping [vuejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) →
    [vue.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)
    will be created.**

(эти значения включают удалённые вопросы и исключают пересекающиеся метки)

### Результаты объединения

```
updating post history, 4 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 4 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 4 rows affected
destroying 'vuejs': [vuejs] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 902
tag remapping of [vue.js] and [vuejs] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Answer (score 1):

Объединить однозначно стоит, так как это синонимы.

Как обычно посмотрим, что на большом so с этими тэгами:

- `vue.js` — [основная метка](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info), 27к вопросов, два синонима: просто `vue` и с точкой `vuejs`
- `vuejs2` — [вторая версия](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vuejs2/info) библиотеки (11к вопросов), есть один синоним — `vue2`

Предлагаю сделать таким же образом: по просто vue.js у нас больше вопросов, а по второй версии у нас не спрашивали пока вопросов.

Comment: Странно, что не задавали по Vue 2. Она же уже не новая, да и к тому же основная (или я неправ?)

Comment: @smellyshovel многие забивают на метки и просто ставят vue.js без версии. Так же и в html, php и тд.